# How Zscaler enables system wide proxy?

Tags: proxy, filtering

I have Zscaler service installed on my system and it does a good job of filtering content and malicious websites.

I was wondering how does Zscaler manage to do this? I read that it creates a PAC file that is saved on your system which contains the policy to divert requests.

Would be great if someone could explain the process flow and technology behind it?

Comment: Have you looked up vendor documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [ZScaler Client Connector Help > Getting Started > What is Zscaler Client Connector?](https://help.zscaler.com/z-app/what-zscaler-app) it creates on desktop devices (Windows, MacOS) a local network adapter where all traffic passes through:

> **How does Zscaler Client Connector work?**
> ...
> When you install
> Zscaler Client Connector for PC, a Zscaler Network Adapter is also
> installed on your user's computer. When the user connects to the web,
> the network adapter captures web traffic from that device.

While it does not use the term "VPN" here in the context of desktop devices it is essentially similar to a VPN. This also means that it affects all traffic on the machine, not only traffic from the browsers.

With mobile devices it even specifically says that a VPN is created:

> When you install Zscaler Client Connector on a mobile device, ...
> ... The device then establishes a local VPN tunnel that captures
> application traffic and directs it to Zscaler Client Connector on the
> device.